# Center every item vertically in the div using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center everything within this div vertically.

First I made that my background view extends my container nicely across the screen and now within that div I want to make columns. If I make columns, `position:relative` does not work.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top_block">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3 class="">My Website</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                Other Content
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.top_block {

    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(33,35,38,1);


    &::before {
        content: "";
        height: inherit;
        width: 10000px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: -1;
        background-color: rgba(33,35,38,1);
        left: -2000px;

    }

    h3 {
        color:white;


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean center vertically the 2 col-md-* div in `.top_block` div that is height only 50px? Or do you want center in the page keeping the bootstrap4 grid system layout?

Comment: Just the .top_block

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3 class="">My Website</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      Other Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: or you can do - 

**position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);**

and **position: relative;** to the correspond parent div.